# Will there be an induced EMF if the windings have no resistance?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage

Imagine a transformer, the primary has a voltage source, a 5 Ohms resistor, and obviously the windings too. If there were no resistance on the windings will there be any emf induced on the secondary side, knowing that the voltage drop only happens in the primary resistor.

Answer (score 1):

> If there were no resistance on the windings will there be any emf induced on the secondary side

Yes

> the voltage drop only happens in the primary resistor

This is not correct. There will still be a voltage drop across the windings even with no resistance in the windings. For an inductor the current and voltage relationship for self inductance is $v=L \frac{d}{dt} i $ and for mutual inductance is $v_1=M \frac{d}{dt} i_2$. So there can be a nonzero voltage across the inductor even without any resistance.

Comment: But using V=I.R, how is it possible to have Voltage without resistance?

Comment: Ohm’s law is not universal. It applies only for resistors. An inductor is not a resistor. Inductors do not use Ohm’s law, they use the one I posted above.

Comment: So even if the windings has no resistance, there still would be a voltage induced on the secondary transformer?

Comment: Yes. $v_2=M \frac{d}{dt} i_1$

Comment: Can you explain the symbols there briefly?

Comment: t is time, v is voltage, i is current, 1 and 2 identify the primary and secondary respectively, and M is the mutual inductance.

Comment: Thankyou, and by the way Dale, let's assume the primary winding have 10 V and the secondary has the same windings, in an ideal transformer, a 10VAC will be induced, if that secondary transformer is connected to a load of 5Ohms, then there would be 2A flowing, am I right?

Comment: Yes, but usually you should ask new questions as a new question instead of in comments. The moderators don’t like extended discussion in comments